# Disable module for specific site or enable module for specific sites

Tags: nginx, webdav, nextcloud

I'm running `nginx-1.21.4` with `dav-ext` module compiled in nginx as dynamic module. The thing is this module intereferes with Nextcloud SabreDAV functionallity so I would like to know how (1)how to completely disable the module for a specific site, (2) enable the module for specific sites or (3) disable the `dav_ext` module functionality per site.

The nginx module in question is https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module.git

Hope someone can help.

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I assume that you're using different `server {}` directives for your sites, so module/methods you using has the ability to switch configuration contexts. So I don't think that you need to disable something intentionally per server `{}` block

Comment: The thing is dav_ext module is interfering with Nextcloud's SabreDav, so what are you proposing? I need this module enabled for other sites/web apps but completely disabled for Nextcloud. Thank you so much.

Comment: you can build and launch several instances of `nginx` each as a backend on its own port and do `proxy_pass` to exact instance (with dav module you need) with a frontend (can be nginx as well)